# My empty elements showing overflow,vin html and css grid

Tags: html, css, grid, element, overflow

I have a few elements in my page mostly empty but when i wrote a few lines of css i got some elements showing. they are causing other elements to overflow. i used grid display on my wrapper, then position: fixed on my banner text liner. the others are just normal  css codes i do.

i have disabled and done few re-writings but still can't get it right.
read a few suggestions but seem not to be helpful to my specific issue.

html

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Hold only four elements banner, header, article, footer -->
        <div class="banner-text">Welcome text</div>
        <header class="main-header">
            <h1>Header group</h1>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul class="navBar">
                <li class="list"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="list">About Us</li>
                <li class="list">Know MP</li>
                <li class="list">Wa-East</li>
                <li class="list">Our Party</li>
                <li class="list">Activities</li>
                <li class="list">Contact Us</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </header>
        <section class="mp"> <h1>MP Column</h1></section>
        <section class="jm"> <h1>JM Colum</h1></section>
        <section class="parliament"> <h1>Parliament</h1></section>
         <article class="main-article"> <h1>Header group</h1></article>
        <main> <h1>Header group</h1></main>
        <aside>Aside  <h1>Header group</h1></aside>
        <footer class="main-footer"> <h1>footer group</h1></footer>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body
{
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
#wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(9, minmax(100px, auto));
}
.banner-text {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-column: span 12;
    background: #262626;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.main-header {
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    grid-column: 1 / 13;
    background: #abb8c3;
}
section.mp {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: span 4;
    background: #c0a16b;
}
section.jm {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: span 4;
    background: #ff00cc;
}
section.parliament {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: span 4;
    background: #aaa093;
}
.main-article {
    grid-row: span 2;
    grid-column: span 8;
    background: #cc6426;
}
main {
    grid-row: span 3;
    grid-column: span 8;
    background: #08b280;
}
aside {
    grid-row: 4 / 9;
    grid-column: 9 / 13;
    background: #eedd75;
}
.main-footer {
    grid-row: 9;
    grid-column: span 12;
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

It's common to run into overflow issues when using CSS grid and/or position: fixed. You can try adding overflow: hidden; to the wrapper element to prevent any content from overflowing and causing layout issues. Another solution is to adjust the height of the elements that are causing overflow or their parent containers to ensure that they fit within the designated grid cells. You can also try adjusting the grid-template-rows property to allocate more space for the overflowing elements. Additionally, you can use the CSS property box-sizing: border-box; to make sure padding and borders are included in the specified width and height of each element.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(9, minmax(100px, auto));
    overflow: hidden; /* Add overflow property to prevent content from overflowing */
}

.banner-text {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-column: span 12;
    background: #262626;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.main-header {
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    grid-column: 1 / 13;
    background: #abb8c3;
}

section.mp {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: span 4;
    background: #c0a16b;
}

section.jm {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: span 4;
    background: #ff00cc;
}

section.parliament {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: span 4;
    background: #aaa093;
}

.main-article {
    grid-row: span 2;
    grid-column: span 8;
    background: #cc6426;
}

main {
    grid-row: span 3;
    grid-column: span 8;
    background: #08b280;
}

aside {
    grid-row: 4 / 9;
    grid-column: 9 / 13;
    background: #eedd75;
}

.main-footer {
    grid-row: 9;
    grid-column: span 12;
    background: #000;
}
Here's an updated version of your CSS with the changes I suggested:
```

```html
  <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Hold only four elements banner, header, article, footer -->
        <div class="banner-text">Welcome text</div>
        <header class="main-header">
            <h1>Header group</h1>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul class="navBar">
                <li class="list"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="list">About Us</li>
                <li class="list">Know MP</li>
                <li class="list">Wa-East</li>
                <li class="list">Our Party</li>
                <li class="list">Activities</li>
                <li class="list">Contact Us</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </header>
        <section class="mp"> <h1>MP Column</h1></section>
        <section class="jm"> <h1>JM Colum</h1></section>
        <section class="parliament"> <h1>Parliament</h1></section>
         <article class="main-article"> <h1>Header group</h1></article>
        <main> <h1>Header group</h1></main>
        <aside>Aside  <h1>Header group</h1></aside>
        <footer class="main-footer"> <h1>footer group</h1></footer>

    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/soorush/9dx4mpw3/28/

Comment: Hi thank you two for the post replies, i came back tried both methods and achieved the results needed, thank you once again. am actually new trying to create some pages using grid-layout. am sure i will be back out here with further issues to seek help.